# Bouncing between & redefining windows

Tags: java, swing

After two weeks of butting my head trying to figure this out myself, I'm sort of at the end of my wits.

Supposed to be writing a program for Java class that uses two windows:

- First window displays an image of a face (generated using drawing primitives)
- Second window displays controls to modify different components of the face (eyes, etc)

Drawing the face, check.
Picking the components of the face, check.
Getting the controls to modify the components, check.

The problem I'm stuck at is getting the second window to change controls based on the component picked (via mouseclick on the image).

Do I need to completely redefine the second window every time a different component is selected or is there a way to simply change the buttons & sliders without redoing the second window every time?

DrawPanel.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel
{   
    public Color[] faceColors = { Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.MAGENTA };
    public int target = 0;
    public String targetName = "";
    private int xPos = 350, yPos = 350;
    private int xDim = 500, yDim = 500;
    private Color faceColor = Color.GREEN;
    int eW, eH, eY, eX1, eX2;

    private int eyeX = 100, eyeY = 150;
    private int eyeSize = 100;
    private Color eyeColor = Color.BLUE;

    private int nose = 1, noseW = 100, noseH = 150, noseY = 75;
    private int mouth = 1, mouthW = 150, mouthH = 30, mouthY = 100;

    private MyShape[] shapes; // array containing all the shapes

    private JLabel statusLabel; // label displaying mouse coordinates

    private ControlFrame inspect;

    // constructor
    public DrawPanel( JLabel status )
    {
        shapes = new MyShape[ 50 ]; // create the array
        setBackground( Color.WHITE ); // set a white background

        // add the mouse listeners
        MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler();
        addMouseListener( mouseHandler );
        addMouseMotionListener( mouseHandler );

        // set the status label for displaying mouse coordinates
        statusLabel = status;

        //  Load the default image
        initDrawing();


        inspect = new ControlFrame();
        inspect.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        inspect.setLocation( 764, 32 );
        inspect.setSize( 200, 700 );
        inspect.setResizable( false );
        inspect.setVisible( true );

    } // end DrawPanel constructor

    public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
    {
        super.paintComponent( g );

        for ( int i = 0; i < 50; i++ )
        {
            if ( shapes[i] != null )
            {
                shapes[ i ].draw( g );
            }
        }
    } // end method paintComponent

    public void initDrawing()
    {
        defineFace( faceColor );
        defineEyes( eyeColor );
        defineMouth( mouth, mouthW, faceColor );
        defineNose( nose, noseY );
    }

    public void defineFace ( Color faceCol )
    {   //  Create the face & ears
        eW = (int)Math.round( xDim / 4 );
        eH = (int)Math.round( yDim / 4 );
        eY = (int)Math.round( yPos - ( yDim / 2 ) );
        eX1 = (int)Math.round( xPos - ( xDim / 2 ) );
        eX2 = (int)Math.round( xPos - eW + ( xDim / 2 ) );

        shapes[0] = new MyOval( eX1, eY, eX1+eW, eY+eH, faceCol, true );
        shapes[1] = new MyOval( eX1, eY, eX1+eW, eY+eH, Color.BLACK, false );
        shapes[2] = new MyOval( eX2, eY, eX2+eW, eY+eH, faceCol, true );
        shapes[3] = new MyOval( eX2, eY, eX2+eW, eY+eH, Color.BLACK, false );
        shapes[4] = new MyOval( eX1, eY, eX1+xDim, eY+yDim, faceCol, true );
        shapes[5] = new MyOval( eX1, eY, eX1+xDim, eY+yDim, Color.BLACK, false );
        for ( int i = 6; i < 10; i++ )
            shapes[i] = null;
    }

    public void defineEyes ( Color eyeCol )
    {   //  Create the eyes
        eW = (int)Math.round( eyeSize * 1.2 );
        eH = (int)Math.round( eyeSize * 0.8 );
        eY = (int)Math.round( yPos - eyeY );
        eX1 = (int)Math.round( xPos - eyeX - ( eW / 2 ) );
        eX2 = (int)Math.round( xPos + eyeX - ( eW / 2 ) );
        //  Whites of Eyes
        shapes[10] = new MyOval( eX1, eY, eX1+eW, eY+eH, Color.WHITE, true );
        shapes[11] = new MyOval( eX1, eY, eX1+eW, eY+eH, Color.BLACK, false );
        shapes[12] = new MyOval( eX2, eY, eX2+eW, eY+eH, Color.WHITE, true );
        shapes[13] = new MyOval( eX2, eY, eX2+eW, eY+eH, Color.BLACK, false );
        //  Irises of eyes
        eW = (int)Math.round( eyeSize * 0.8 );
        eX1 = (int)Math.round( xPos - eyeX - ( eW / 2 ) );
        eX2 = (int)Math.round( xPos + eyeX - ( eW / 2 ) );
        shapes[14] = new MyOval( eX1, eY, eX1+eW, eY+eH, eyeCol, true );
        shapes[15] = new MyOval( eX1, eY, eX1+eW, eY+eH, Color.BLACK, false );
        shapes[16] = new MyOval( eX2, eY, eX2+eW, eY+eH, eyeCol, true );
        shapes[17] = new MyOval( eX2, eY, eX2+eW, eY+eH, Color.BLACK, false );
        eH = (int)Math.round( eyeSize * 0.6 );
        shapes[18] = new MyOval( eX1+eW/4, eY+eW/4, eX1+eH, eY+eH, Color.BLACK, true );
        shapes[19] = new MyOval( eX2+eW/4, eY+eW/4, eX2+eH, eY+eH, Color.BLACK, true );
        for ( int i = 20; i < 30; i++ )
            shapes[i] = null;
    }

    public void defineMouth ( int style, int width, Color faceCol )
    {   //  Create the mouth
        switch ( style )
        {   //  Construct default mouth
            case 1: shapes[30] = new MyOval( xPos-width, yPos+mouthY-mouthH, xPos+width, yPos+mouthY+mouthH, Color.PINK, true );
                    for ( int i = 31; i < 39; i++ )
                        shapes[i] = null;
                    shapes[39] = new MyOval( xPos-width, yPos+mouthY-mouthH*2, xPos+width, yPos+mouthY, faceCol, true );
                    break;
            //  More definitions to come
        }
    }

    public void defineNose ( int style, int height )
    {   //  Create the nose
        switch ( style )
        {   //  Construct default nose
            case 1: shapes[40] = new MyOval( xPos-noseW/2, yPos-height, xPos+noseW/2, yPos-height+noseH, Color.BLACK, true );
                    for ( int i = 41; i < 50; i++ )
                        shapes[i] = null;
                    break;
            //  More definitions to come
        }
    }

   // handles mouse events for this JPanel
   private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter
      implements MouseMotionListener
   {
       // creates and sets the initial position for the new shape
       public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e )
       {
           if ( target > 0 && target < 10 || target == 39 ) 
           {
               inspect.select( 1 );
               targetName = "face";
           }
           else if ( target > 9 && target < 30 ) 
           {
               inspect.select( 2 );
               targetName = "eyes";
           }
           else if ( target > 29 && target < 39 ) 
           {
               inspect.select( 3 );
               targetName = "mouth";
           }
           else if ( target > 39 && target < 48 ) 
           {
               inspect.select( 4 );
               targetName = "nose";
           }
           else 
           {
               inspect.select( 0 );
               targetName = "none";
           }
       } // end method mousePressed

       // updates the status bar to show the current mouse coordinates
       public void mouseMoved( MouseEvent e )
       {
           int x = e.getX();
           int y = e.getY();
           target = 0;
           for ( int i = 49; i >= 0; i--)
           {
               if ( shapes[i] != null )
               {
                   if ( x > shapes[i].getX1() && x < shapes[i].getX2() )
                   {
                       if ( y > shapes[i].getY1() && y < shapes[i].getY2() )
                       {
                           target = i;
                           break;
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

           statusLabel.setText(String.format( "(%d,%d)  ", e.getX(), e.getY() ) + inspect.picked() );
       } // end method mouseMoved
   } // end class MouseHandler
} // end class DrawPanel
```

Comment: Without code to look at, this will be just too open to be discussed. Can you create a "simple" example of your problem that we can take a look at?

Comment: Basically, what I might do, is define a "Drawing" object of some kind, that know how to paint itself, based on properties supplied to it, but could also list all the available properties that the object supports.  This might not only require the name of the property, but it's type and possibly even it's bound values (min/max or acceptable values)...

Comment: By making the control window a child of the display window, could I get by with something as simple as using super()?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking but I think you're looking for the [`removeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#removeAll%28%29) method. It will remove the existing controls so you can place the new ones. Something like:

```
void inspect(int thing) {
    removeAll();
    if (thing == 0) { // nothing
        add(new JLabel("Nothing selected")); 
    } else if (thing == 1) { // face
        JComboBox faceColors = new JComboBox(
            new String[] { "Green", "Yellow", "Magenta" });
        faceColors.addItemListener(...);
        add(faceColors);
    } else {
        // etc
    }
    pack();
}
```